# Tarballing without Git metadata

Tags: find, packaging, tar, xargs, grep

My source tree contains several directories which are using Git source control, and I need to tarball the whole tree excluding any references to the Git metadata or custom log files.

I thought I'd have a go using a combination of find/egrep/xargs/tar, but somehow the tar file contains the .git directories and the *.log files.

This is what I have:

```
find -type f . | egrep -v '\.git|\.log' | xargs tar rvf ~/app.tar
```

Can someone explain my misunderstanding here? Why is tar processing the files that find and egrep are filtering?

I'm open to other techniques as well.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

You will get a nasty surprise when the number of files increase to more than one `xargs` command: Then you will first make a tar file of the first files and then overwrite the same tar file with the rest of the files.

GNU `tar` has the `--exclude` option which will solve this issue:

```
tar cvf ~/app.tar --exclude .git --exclude "*.log" .
```

Answer (score 58):

You can try directly with the tar option --exclude-vcs:

```
--exclude-vcs:
          Exclude version control system directories
```

For example:

```
tar cvfj nameoffile.tar.bz2 directory/ --exclude-vcs
```

It works with Git.

Comment: Thanks but "Option --exclude-vcs is not supported" with my version of tar.

Comment: @zaf yes = GNU tar only.  MacOSX ships with bsdtar which doesn't have it.

Comment: @Marko Aha, thanks for enlightening me. These details bug me always.

Answer (score 17):

Try something like this:

```
git archive --format=tar -o ~/tarball.tar -v HEAD
```

Add your .log files and everything else you don't want to be packed to your .gitignore file.

Comment: nice, is there a way to get a snapshot of code without making a commit tho? I want to archive the current directory even if files are not staged or committed?

Answer (score 13):

To exclude version control system directories:

`tar --exclude-vcs`

This will exclude svn, git metafiles etc.

Answer (score 5):

The newer GNU tar has the option to exclude version control directories automatically by using flag --exclude-vcs . This will take care of .git as well.

Answer (score 4):

[slap] Bah! The parameters to find were in the wrong order! I didn't see the warnings because they whizzed off the screen. This allowed '.' to pass through egrep which caused tar to slurp up everything.

That will teach me for drowning important messages in verbose debug.

This works:

```
find . -type f | egrep -v '\.git|\.log' | xargs tar cvf ~/app.tar
```

Answer (score 3):

[git-archive](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-archive.html) may be what you're looking for.

Comment: Probably not. Since it's multiple gits in the source tree.

Answer (score 3):

You could do that without grep. find is powerful

```
 find . -type f -not \( -iname ".git" -or -iname ".log" \) | xargs ...
```

Comment: The problem was my find parameters. See my answer. Thanks for the alternative.

Answer (score 2):

For doing it from outside the app directory:

```
tar cvfz app.tar.gz --exclude ".git/*" --exclude ".git" app/
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, the `.gitignore` content is what I needed:

`tar cvfz $PROJECT.tar.gz --exclude-from=$PROJECT/.gitignore $PROJECT`

`--exclude-from` is reading the file's contents - and exlucde the patterns listed there

Comment: there's also --exclude-vcs-ignores which reads exclude patterns from the VCS ignore files.